# Rails 3.1: Calling a template via JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I was just going through [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2)

old rails cast episode, and one thing it mentions is the (now obsolete, apparently) link_to_function code. One interesting snippet it mentions is

```
 link_to_function "Add a Task" do |page|
    page.insert_html :bottom, :tasks, :partial => 'task', :object => Task.new
  end
```

In short, clicking the "Add a Task" link appends the "task" partial to the page without ajax.

I'm familiar with how to do this in Rails 3/3.1 via AJAX and/or manual javascript, but how do you pull in a template partial on the fly without touching ajax?

Comment: I'd guess that it inserts the partial's HTML at the bottom of the page in a hidden `<div>` and then some JavaScript clones it and inserts the clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just simply stores the html content within the javascript code, which it's rendered while the page is rendered. So when you click "Add a task" the partial is already there escaped in the javascript code of the add task action. Just take a look to the content of the page with firebug.

Also the docs shows that the `instert_html` looks like this for prototype:

```
def insert_html(position, id, *options_for_render)
  content = javascript_object_for(render(*options_for_render))
  record "Element.insert(\"#{id}\", { #{position.to_s.downcase}: #{content} });"
end
```

So you can see that the content is actually the `task` partial, and it's inserted into javascript code.
Also i have to mention that this is an **obtrusive** way to use javascript.

Take a look at the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods/insert_html).

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same railscast, and I figured out the reason why this is not working is because this method uses Prototype, which by default is unavailable with the Rails 3.1 .

You could get this working by installing prototype gem from:

https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails